# How can I find_all or select multiple attribute names using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, attributes, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find_all or select 4 names of attributes from a website using Beautiful Soup.

I am new to python and could not find this answer elsewhere. I am using Python 3.4.3 and the most updated Beautiful Soup.

td is the element of the website html
the attributes are text, linkb, pnum, and num

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get(url)           #downloads website html

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)         #soup calls the data

v_data = soup.select('.text', '.pnum', '.num', '.linkb') #these are the names of the attributes
for symbol in v_data:
        print(symbol.text)
```

If I use the code, it does not work.

I can't just search the attribute td or any other single attribute because it will find or select many other values from the website that I do not want.

```
v_data = soup.select('.text')
```

This works but does not return the other attribute names.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup's CSS Selector support is limited.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

How about using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) which has [better css selector support](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html).

```
import lxml.html

r = requests.get(url)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
v_data = root.cssselect('.text, .pnum, .num, .linkb')
for symbol in v_data:
    print(symbol.text)
```

**UPDATE** according to OP's comment:

Instead of specifying all `td`'s class, you can pick a table that contains those rows, and iterate the rows:

```
table = soup.select('table.mdcTable')[0]
for row in table.select('tr')[1:]:
    print [td.text.strip() for td in row.select('td')[1:]]
```

Comment: Now the program works but I still have a problem. This method selects all .text, then .pnum, then .num, then linkb. This is unfortunately ineffective for what I am trying to do. I am trying to scrape from http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnnm-gainer-20150731.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar. I only want the name of the stock and the 4 numerical values to its right. I want this program to upload each stock (100) on the list and their values.

Comment: I actually did this and it worked:    v_data = soup.select('tr')[3:103] 

    for symbol in v_data:
        print(symbol.text)